# How to get lightning:input field value in Controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm trying to get lightning: input field value in my component controller but its either giving me undefined value if I don't define a default value in my attribute or giving me default value.

Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="booleanvalue" type="boolean" default="false"/>

    <lightning:input type="checkbox" value="{!v.booleanvalue}" label="Test Checkbox"/> 

    <lightning:button label="Save" onclick="{! c.handleSave}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    handleSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('>>> save method... '+component.get("v.booleanvalue"));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" checked="{!v.booleanvalue}" label="Test Checkbox"/>
```

Comment: With boolean attribute its working but if I use object.CustomField__c, I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CustomField__c' of null error

Comment: How are you getting the value for the CustomField__c ? It is a boolean data type, right?

Comment: Yes, its boolean data type and that's how I have declared the attribute <aura:attribute name="customObject" type="CustomObject__c" />